# Add token parameter to all urls inside an asp.net mvc 2 site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, authentication

I've integrated some pages written in ASP.NET MVC 2, into a classic webform app.
Everything works well except the authentication system.

The authentication system is using some token added to the url like :

```
/Account/Profil/Details.aspx?AUTHID=2ddc098a-cf0b-fd81-afb7-d41f35010b9f
```

When i reach my asp.net mvc pages (all these pages must be secured), they must include that AUTHID parameter.

I'm using the core Webform control to secure the pages, and this control check for the AUTHID token in the url. So basicly my route must include the

```
?AUTHID=2ddc098a-cf0b-fd81-afb7-d41f35010b9f
```

What the best and clever way to do this ?
I don't want to pass the AUTHID parameter manually in all controller actions.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can save the AuthId in the Session object and create a custom Authorize Attribute.

**Attribute**

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // your custom logic depending on Session["AuthId"]
        return httpContext.Session["AuthId"] != null;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [CustomAuthorize]
    public ActionResult MyActionMethod()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**hope this helps**

Comment: Unfortunatly i can't save the AUTHID into a session and check the session because the control that handle the authentication check for the parameter into the url. Basicly i need to change all my url and include that AUTHID. Hope it make sense.

Comment: You can change your authentification logic or have both working with the implementation in my answer. I would create a custom class so you dont have the logic twice and call it from your control and the custom attribute.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. He asks for adding to the route/url and session is not a part of that.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem by extending the ASP.NET routing mechanism. Just create a custom route and override the GetVirtualPath function.

```
public class TokenizedRoute : Route
{
  public TokenizedRoute(string url, IRouteHandler routeHandler) : base(url, routeHandler)
  {
  }

  public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
  {
    string tokenValue = "your token value";
    values.Add("AUTHID", tokenValue);

    return base.GetVirtualPath(requestContext, values);
  }
}
```

See [my blog post](http://vladimirgoncharov.blogspot.ch/2013/10/propagate-url-parameter-through-links-generated-by-mvc.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a jQuery solution to append a token to the query string of all links:

```
$("a").each(function (index, link)
{
    $(link).attr("href", $(link).attr("href") + "?AUTHID=" + token);
});
```

But I agree with dknaack, I would say you should reconsider your authentication logic if at all possible.